# How to create persona pieces for Minecraft Bedrock?

Tags: minecraft-modding, minecraft-bedrock-modding

I'm learning addons creation for Minecraft Bedrock. I learned about the creation of resource packs and behaviour packs, following some tutorials like the ones [provided by FoxyNoTail](https://foxynotail.com/how-to/).

Now I want to create pieces for character creator, like the ones in the screenshots below. I searched everywhere for docs/tutorials on this subject, and found nothing.

[image: Back items on character creator screen]

I see there are items divided in *Body* and *Style* sections, each with their own subsections. I digged through the documentations at [bedrock.dev](https://wiki.bedrock.dev/) and [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/minecraft/creator/) sites, but couldn't find anything.

I also searched the game data files, where there are some `manifest.json` files with modules of type `persona_piece`, but this type of module is not documented anywhere.

I believe it must be in a resource pack, is it right? If it is so, how should the `manifest.json` file be structured?

Any hints?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I posted an [issue at Minecraft Creator repository](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/minecraft-creator/issues/281) about this question. The answer is that, to be able to create persona pieces, one must be participant of the [Minecraft Partner Program](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/partner). There's documentation on the subject, but its access is restricted to partners.

To apply to the program, it's needed to develop and provide a portfolio of high quality content created and shared with the community (maps, realms, addons, skins, hosted servers).

So, I don't think it's possible for beginners to create persona pieces, at least not right now.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a resource pack then activate that in the global resource but that is very complex and you would need to make models animation if you want some very complex. You can start by make a model of you want to make then you can make the texture then put the model where you want it to be on the player then last you could add some animations this could easily be done on [blockbench](https://blockbench.net)

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it explained *how* to do this.